# Was ist die Hutschnur – und warum platzt sie mir?

Tags: etymology, phrase

Letztens war mal wieder so ein Tag, an dem mir fast sämtliche Pferde durchgegangen wären. Und so liege ich jetzt zuhause, erinnere mich, wie mir fast *die Hutschnur geplatzt* wäre – und denke mir, was das eigentlich ist?

Ich würde vermuten, dass der Ausdruck mit Hüten zu tun hat, wie sie vor Allem in der ersten Hälfte des 20. Jahrhunderts von (feineren) Herren getragen wurden und wie sie mein Großonkel heute noch trägt. Warum aber eine Hut-*Schnur?* Wo an einem solchen Hut fände sich eine so bezeichnete Schnur, was war ihre Funktion, und warum platzt sie?

Oder bin ich ganz auf dem Holzweg und der Ausdruck hat eine ganz andere Etymologie?

Comment: Das schlägt ja dem Fass den Boden ins Gesicht!

Comment: According to the wikipedia article about [*Hutschnur*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hutschnur), a *Hutschnur* can also *platzen* ;-)

Comment: @Philipp Das möchte ich mal sehen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hier handelt es sich wie schon gesagt um eine Kontamination (Quervermischung) der beiden Redensarten:

- Mir platzt der Kragen
- Das geht (mir) über die Hutschnur

(ähnlich wie "das schlägt dem Fass den Boden ins Gesicht"), die so oft im selben Kontext verwendet werden, dass sie sich im Sprachgebrauch vermischen. Man findet auch "da reißt mir die Hutschnur" - Das scheint eine Gemengelage<sup>1</sup> aus "da reißt mir der Geduldsfaden" und der Hutschnur zu sein.

Das mit dem Kragen dürfte offensichtlich sein: Bei Wut schwillt der Hals - er wird dick - (siehe auch "ich hab' 'nen dicken Hals"), der Kragen platzt.

Die Hutschnur ist etwas komplexer. Damit ist erstmal nicht der *Fangriemen* oder die *Fangschnur* unterm Kinn gemeint, die man z.B. an einem Cowboyhut findet und den Hut fangen soll, wenn er z.B. bei einem Windstoß vom Kopf fliegt, sondern eine Schnur oder ein Band, das zwischen Krempe und Kappe angebracht ist und für die dauerhafte Passform den Hut daran hindern soll, sich auf dem Kopf zu weiten.

Es kursieren mehrere mögliche (und alle für sich wahrscheinlich unbewiesene) Erklärungen für diese Redensart, die ganz generell "das geht zu weit" bedeutet:

- Man stelle sich vor, jemand geht "bis zur Hutschnur" ins Wasser oder versinkt in einem Sumpf - Dann *steht im das Wasser* eindeutig schon weiter als *bis zum Hals* und das "geht zu weit". Auch diese Erklärung ist ziemlich offensichtlich.
- Ganz allgemein kann man sagen, dass die Hutschnur hauptsächlich die Weite des Hutes bestimmt und damit ein Maß für die Obergrenze der Größe des Kopfes angibt. Diese Obergrenze lässt sich natürlich auch auf alles Mögliche übertragen.
- Es existiert eine weitere Erklärung ([die der Duden allerdings für fraglich hält](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hutschnur)), nach der Wasserentnahme aus einer Quelle früher "auf die Dicke einer Hutschnur" begrenzt war, und mehr (also ein dickerer Strahl) demnach zu viel war.

<sup>1</sup> Auch ein Wort, das mal 'ne Frage wert wäre.

Comment: Die "Gemengelage" bedarf weniger einer Frage als mehr einer bewussten Verwendung (statt der sehr häufigen fehlerhaften).

Answer (score 2):

To add to @tofro 's comment:

> Eine so genannte Kontamination: Vermischung der beiden Redensarten "es geht einem etwas über die Hutschnur" und "es platzt einem der Kragen"

https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~jemandem+platzt+die+Hutschnur&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou

Comment: Das ist allerdings keine schöne Antwort. Denn es steht immer noch die Frage im Raum: *Was* ist überhaupt die Hutschnur? Und: Es wäre viel besser, wenn die beiden vermischten Redensarten zumindest angeschnitten erklärt werden.

Comment: Werden sie doch hinter dem Link, den ich bereitgestellt habe. Ich wollte nicht den gesamten Inhalt der Seite copy-pasten. Mein Beitrag war eher als Ergänzung zu @tofro gedacht. Eine Hutschnur ist die Schnur um einen Hut. Google bringt da gute Ergebnisse: http://max-attachments.prod.hlpstr.de/attachments/articles/icons/000/213/626/featured/71261835.jpg

Comment: Auf Stackexchange werden Antworten, die nur aus einem Link oder aus wenig mehr als nur einem Link bestehen, nicht gerne gesehen und oft gelöscht. Das Prinzip von SE soll sein, dass die Antwort *auf der Seite* zu finden ist, insbesondere um sich ändernde Links anderer Seiten abzufangen. Für weitere Erklärung siehe [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231)

Comment: @Jan: Danke für die Info. Dies war mir allerdings schon bewusst. Es liegt mir fern tofro seine/ihre Antwort abzunehmen, insofern war mein Beitrag nur als Ergänzung gedacht. Ich hätte auch kommentiert, wenn ich dazu bereits die Berechtigung gehabt hätte. tofros Antwort liegt inzwischen vor und enthält alle aufgekommenen Punkte. Die Antwort ist also auf der Seite zu finden.

Comment: @BestGuess: zu Kommentaren lies bitte den [entsprechenden Meta-Post](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment). Kommentare sind nicht dazu geeignet Antworten oder Halbantworten zu geben, dazu gibt es schließlich die Antwortbox.

Comment: @Takkat Dein Kommentar steht in ziemlichem Widerspruch zu dem von Jan. Wenn man nur eine kleine Ergänzung zu einer Antwort von jemand anderem machen will, wohin damit? Für eine eigenständige Antwort ist es viel zu wenig und wird unter Umständen für geringe Qualität/geringen Umfang kritisiert (so wie in diesem Fall). Bliebe nur noch als dritte Option, die eigene Ergänzung in die fremde Antwort hineinzueditieren - da hätte ich ganz eindeutig ein ungutes Gefühl. Mal ganz abgesehen davon, dass BestGuess als neues Mitglied sowieso fremde Beiträge noch nicht editieren kann.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: kleine Ergänzungen kommen mit einem Edit in eine existierende Antwort. Wenn es mehr ist, dann sollte man daraus eine eine eigene Antwort basteln. Das ist auf allen S.E. Seiten so. [Kommentare sind nur als **temporäre** Hinweise gedacht](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), die jederzeit gelöscht werden können. Alles "wertvolle" muss zwingend in einer Antwort stehen, damit es nicht verloren geht.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: Jeder, auch ein nicht registrierter User kann einen Editvorschlag machen, der dann von anderen Usern noch abgesegnet werden muss. Das gibt sogar Reputationspunkte!

Comment: @Takkat: und nun erklär mir noch, wie man einen edit vorschlag zu einem fremden kommentar macht (darum geht es hier nämlich ursprünglich), dann wird auch ein Schuh draus.

Comment: @BestGuess: warum würde man einen Kommentar editieren wollen? Unter Kommentaren zu deinem eigenen Beitrag kannst du immer kommentieren, für Kommentare überall brauchst du halt 50 Reputationspunkte, die du z.B. in kürzester Zeit mit ein paar guten Editvorschlägen leicht erreichen kannst.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Takkats und meine Kommentare ergänzen sich perfekt, weil wir grundsätzlich vom gleichen Modell ausgehen.

Comment: @Takkat: meine "Antwort" habe ich gepostet als es hier noch keine Antwort gab, sondern lediglich den einzelnen Kommentar von tofro unter der Frage (deshalb auch mein Einleitungssatz "To add to tofro 's comment". Da ihr mir noch immer nicht aufgezeigt habt, wie man in dieser Situation sinnvoll zur Diskussion beiträgt, nehme ich euren Input dankend an, er ist aber denkbar untauglich in diesem Fall.

Comment: @BestGuess: Es gibt eine ganz gute Antwort zu dem [letzten diesbezüglichen Meta-Post](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment).